# How to run node.js application using eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I am beginner for node.js and i tried to install node.js on my Ubuntu 14.04  i installed node.js and its working fine when i am running a sample program using cmd. After that i installed node.js plugin on my eclipse and created a new project to test. Then i clicked on the file and Run as  node application. on the console it shows nothing. actually i just printed

```
     console.log("Hello")
```

Can u guys help to proper installation and run application using eclipse.

Comment: I think `console.log` will show output in the browser console.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 no, in nodejs console writes on the terminal

Comment: @Shaharyar good to know. Does it suppress printing to browser console, too?

Comment: Actually node runs on server, so it has nothing to do with browser level debugging. Only the client side code can write on browser's console.

Comment: i mean not in browser console on the eclipse console. can anyone tell me some sample code?